# Auto-Mount web server with SSHFS

Tags: sshfs

Okay, I'm running out of ideas here. Because of the password authentication with SSHFS and because SSH keys do not seem to be supported on the web server, I am simply looking for a script I can run @reboot with the crontab.

I tried this python script here (http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=135113) but it just doesn't seem to work. Note that while security is a priority, I am running out of ideas and storing the password as human-readable does not concern me right now. My data server requires a 24hr reboot, and auto-mounting afterwards is a must.

For the purposes of simplicity, lets say my information is as follows:

Remote Server: *server.com*

Remote User: *USER*

Remote Location: */home/USER/USER.server.com*

Local Mount Point: */home/USER/webfolder*

Answer (score 0):

if you use ssh with ssh-key  then you just have to add  your identity to authorized_keys on your server.  more [here](http://sshkeychain.sourceforge.net/mirrors/SSH-with-Keys-HOWTO/SSH-with-Keys-HOWTO-4.html)

after you have done this you can just use sshfs in any cron job without any password